# What is the maxium number of S-foils a spacecraft has had?

Tags: star-wars

The [X-wing fighter](https://www.starwars.com/databank/x-wing-starfighter/) is one of the most iconic spacecraft from Star Wars, mainly thanks to its unique appearance, including it's 4 moving wings ([S-foils](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/S-foils).) What is the maximum number of moving wings (s-foils) that has been seen in Star Wars?

Comment: Do you count the ARC-170 as having 4 or 6?

Comment: @DavidW - 6 by my count. And worthy of adding as an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ARC-170 starfighter](https://www.starwars.com/databank/arc-170-starfighter) appears to have 6 S-foils:

[image: ARC-170 starfighters with S-foils open]